# Force cursor:pointer for link in a div with contenteditable attribute in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, contenteditable

We are using ckeditor in our project and have spotted following issue:

We should show pointer cursor for links within editor (as designed). It works for all browsers except IE.

Simplified HTML:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  <a href="foo.com" style="cursor: pointer;">Link to some site</a>
</div>
```

In IE (tested in v.8 and v.10) it doesn't work.

Any ideas how it can be achieved in IE?

Comment: You have a missing quote, but that's not in your original HTML, is it?

Comment: Yes, sory, just copy/past issue.

Comment: Is this actually a problem? Links inside a contenteditable element aren't followed when you click on them, so the pointer cursor style doesn't seem appropriate.

Comment: Totally agree, but it customer desire. Anyway, right now we ignore this "issue", since no any way founded to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

how about assigning `cursor:pointer;` for `<div contenteditable="true">` ?

alternatively, you can also do it with jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('[contenteditable="true"]').css('cursor','pointer');
});
```

hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not specify it explicitly:
All other content within div with contenteditable should use default cursor ('text'), but for link it should be overridden to 'pointer'.
Anyway, thanks for proposal.